# Get all dates between start date's array and end date's array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, foreach, hook

I have two arrays one with all the start date (arrayStart) and the second with all the end date (arrayEnd).
I need to have all dates between the start and the end date. Each value matches on both array (arrayStart[0] matches arrayEnd[0], how can I do that?

Here is my code :

```
    try {
        let res = await axios.get(`https://myseenapp.herokuapp.com/constructionSite/${_id}`);
        let data = res.data;
        setConstruction(data);

        setStartDate(
            data
                .map(e => e.startDate)
                .forEach((day) => {
                    let convert = day.split('-').reverse().join('-')
                    if (arrayStart.includes(convert) === false) {
                        arrayStart.push(convert)
                    }
                }));
        setEndDate(
            data
                .map(e => e.endDate)
                .forEach((day) => {
                    let convert = day.split('-').reverse().join('-')
                    if (arrayEnd.includes(convert) === false) {
                        arrayEnd.push(convert)
                    }
                })
        );
    const start = (item) => {
        console.log(moment(item).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
    }

    arrayStart.forEach(start);

    const end = (item) => {
        console.log(moment(item).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
    }
    
    arrayEnd.forEach(end);
    let s = start(item);
    const getDaysBetweenDates = (start, end) => {
        let now = start;
        let dates = [];
        while (now <= end){
            dates.push(now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
            now.add(1, 'days');
            dates.forEach((day) => {
            newDaysObject[day] = {
                textColor: "white",
                color: 'gold',
                selected: true,
            }
        })
    }
    return dates;
}
let dateList = getDaysBetweenDates(start, end);
console.log(dateList)

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I need to have all dates between the start and the end date"?

Comment: Hello ! I mean that I need to have all the dates that exist between the startDate and the endDate exemple : startdate = 2021-08-25 and the enddate = 2021-08-28 . I would like to have the 25/26/27/28.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDates()` to get an array of dates b/w two dates. [code link](https://playcode.io/803900/)

```
   Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
       var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
       dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
       return dat;
   }

   function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
      var dateArray = new Array();
      var currentDate = startDate;
      while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push(currentDate)
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
      }
      return dateArray;
    }

    var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(10));
```

Comment: Yes thank you i've already saw something like this, it's working but it's not fixing my pb since I need to refresh ten time to have all my values available ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Are you expecting something like this `DateBetweenRange(startArr, endArr)`

Comment: **INPUT**: `DateBetweenRange([2021-08-25, 2021-08-27],[2021-08-27, 2021-08-28])`

Comment: **OUTPUT**: `[ [2021-08-25, 2021-08-26, 2021-08-27], [2021-08-27, 2021-08-28] ]`

Comment: Hello ! Yes something like this, my main pb is that I need to refresh 10 times to have all my values displayed inside the dates array, I need to find a way to do it more easily